# Google Tag Manager not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My project has two targets, A and B, each target has same code.
I add GTM to my project, so in my GTM account I have two container, A and B.
Container A is tracking target A, and container B is tracking target B.
Also, they have different GA ID.

I already set ContainerID, Tags, Triggers and correct GA tracking ID.
when I run target A, and I can get tracking information in GA.
But when I run target B, I got nothing.

So I try to test my target B.
I create a new property, named testProperty, and change Container B's GA tracking ID (become testProperty's tracking ID)

Then (suddenly!):
The GA reporting has target B tracking information.

So I try to change Container B's GA tracking ID to original ID, It did't work.

Can someone tell me why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

Did you published your change in GTM?  If you did, the GTM SDK doesn't always look for new container versions right away.  Try deleting the app from the simulator/device and running again.

Comment: sorry I reply late. I have published my lastest version.
someday, I found GA has analysis data  finally!
I guess maybe is the GTM sdk doesn't load the lastest version.
thanks your reply :)